Volume of an elliptical cylinder cut with a curved plane
I am looking to find the volume that is left when a curved plane defined by $z=-y^3+0.5$
and the xy plane cuts an elliptical cylinder defined from five points ($Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey=F$). I plan to adjust the curved plane such that it intersects with the ellipse and the xy plane.
The issue is that the ellipse is rotated (as per the image) whereas the plane is perpendicular to the y plane so I can't reduce the ellipse to the standard form $\frac{x^2}{a} + \frac{y^2}{b}=1$. Is it possible to derive this volume using multivariable calculus, and how might I go about doing it?
Would it be better to turn the ellipse into polar form and centre it at the origin somehow?

